# React router not working require modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router.Bundling with browserify + reactify or babelify. /Opa path is working but other routing(components comes from index.js) /Senet path ext. not working.I dont see any errors on console.Whats problem ?

My App JSX

```js
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;
window.React = React;
var mui = require('material-ui'),
  ThemeManager = new mui.Styles.ThemeManager(),
  RaisedButton = mui.RaisedButton;

var App = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
            this.initializeJsLibrary();
    },
   

  
    componentDidUpdate: function(newProps) {
        // its important to pass the new props in
        this.initializeJsLibrary();
    },
    initializeJsLibrary:function(){

        $.material.init();
        var rules = {
         //Select içindeki hidden inputları validate edebilmesi için
            ignore: '',
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                var name = $(element).attr("name");
                error.appendTo($("#" + name + "_val"));

            }
        
        };
        $('#myForm').validate(rules);
        $(":input").inputmask();
        // autoNumeric
        $('.autoNumeric').autoNumeric('init');


        console.log("Scripts worked");

    },
    render: function () {
        console.log(RouteHandler);
        return (
        <p>Selam<RouteHandler {...this.props}  /></p>);
    }
});

var Opp = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (<p>Oppppp</p>)
    }
})
var routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
        <Route name="Opp" path="Opa" handler={Opp} />

        <Route name="FaturaKayitTipi" path="Fatura/Detay/:faturaTipiID" handler={FaturaKayit} />
        <Route name="FaturaFirmaIleKayit" path="Fatura/Detay/:firmaID/:faturaTipiID" handler={FaturaKayit} />
        <Route name="SenetListesi" path="Senet" handler={SenetListesi} />
        <Route name="SenetKayit" path="Senet/Kayit" handler={SenetKayit} />
        <Route name="SenetDuzenle" path="Senet/Kayit/:SenetID" handler={SenetKayit} />
        <Route name="TanimKayit" handler={TanimKayit} />
        <Route name="CalisanListesi" path="Calisan" handler={CalisanListesi} />
        <Route name="CalisanKayit" path="Calisan/Kayit" handler={CalisanKayit} />
        <Route name="CalisanDuzenle" path="Calisan/Kayit/:calisanID" handler={CalisanKayit} />
        <Route name="FirmaListesi" path="Firma" handler={FirmaListesi} />
        <Route name="FirmaKayit" path="Firma/Kayit" handler={FirmaKayit} />
        <Route name="FirmaDuzenle" path="Firma/Kayit/:firmaID" handler={FirmaKayit} />
        <Route name="MasrafListesi" path="Masraf" handler={MasrafListesi} />
        <Route name="KullaniciListesi" path="Kullanici" handler={KullaniciListesi} />
        <Route name="KullaniciKayit" path="Kullanici/Kayit" handler={KullaniciKayit} />
        <Route name="KullaniciDuzenle" path="Kullanici/Kayit/:KullaniciID" handler={KullaniciKayit} />
        <Route name="CalisanMaasListesi" path="CalisanMaas/:CalisanID" handler={CalisanMaasListesi} />
        <Route name="CekListesi" path="Cek" handler={CekListesi} />
        <Route name="CalisanIslemListesi" path="CalisanIslem/:calisanID" handler={CalisanIslemListesi} />
        <Route name="DepoListesi" path="Depo" handler={DepoListesi} />
        <Route name="FaturaListesi" path="Fatura" handler={FaturaListesi} />
        <Route name="UrunListesi" path="Urun" handler={UrunListesi} />
        <Route name="UrunKayit" path="Urun/Kayit" handler={UrunKayit} />
        <Route name="UrunDuzenle" path="Urun/Kayit/:urunID" handler={UrunKayit} />
        <Route name="DepoKayit" path="Depo/Kayit" handler={DepoKayit} />
        <Route name="DepoDuzenle" path="Depo/Kayit/:depoID" handler={DepoKayit} />
        <Route name="CekKayit" path="Cek/Kayit" handler={CekKayit} />
        <Route name="CekDuzenle" path="Cek/Kayit/:cekID" handler={CekKayit} />
        <Route name="MarkaKayit" path="Marka/Kayit" handler={MarkaKayit} />
        <Route name="MarkaDuzenle" path="Marka/Kayit/:depoID" handler={MarkaKayit} />
        <Route name="KategoriListesi" path="Kategori" handler={KategoriListesi} />
        <Route name="KategoriKayit" path="Kategori/Kayit" handler={KategoriKayit} />
        <Route name="KategoriDuzenle" path="Kategori/Kayit/:kategoriID" handler={KategoriKayit} />
  <Route name="HesapListesi" path="Hesap" handler={HesapListesi} />
        <Route name="HesapKayit" path="Hesap/Kayit" handler={HesapKayit} />
        <Route name="HesapDetay" path="Hesap/Detay/:hesapID" handler={HesapDetay} />
        <Route name="FirmaDetay" path="Firma/Detay/:firmaID" handler={FirmaDetay} />
        <Route name="HesapDuzenle" path="Hesap/Kayit/:hesapID" handler={HesapKayit} />
        <Route name="TahsilatKayit" path="Tahsilat/Kayit/:firmaID" handler={TahsilatKayit} />
        <Route name="DepoUrunKayit" path="Depo/UrunEkle" handler={DepoUrunKayit} />
        <Route name="DepoUrunKayitUrun" path="Depo/UrunEkle/Urun/:urunID" handler={DepoUrunKayit} />
        <Route name="DepoUrunKayitDepo" path="Depo/UrunEkle/Depo/:depoID" handler={DepoUrunKayit} />
    </Route>



);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler,state) {
    var params = state.params;
    React.render(<Handler params={params} />, document.getElementById("reactBody"));
});

var FaturaKayit = require("./React/FaturaKayit.jsx");
var AjaxGrid = require("./React/AjaxGrid.jsx");
var AutoComplate = require("./React/AutoComplate.jsx");
var CalisanIslemListesi = require("./React/CalisanIslemListesi.jsx");
var CalisanKayit = require("./React/CalisanKayit.jsx");
var CalisanListesi = require("./React/CalisanListesi.jsx");
var CalisanMaasListesi = require("./React/CalisanMaasListesi.jsx");
var CekKayit = require("./React/CekKayit.jsx");
var CekListesi = require("./React/CekListesi.jsx");
var DepoKayit = require("./React/DepoKayit.jsx");
var DepoListesi = require("./React/DepoListesi.jsx");
var DepoUrunKayit = require("./React/DepoUrunKayit.jsx");
var FaturaKayit = require("./React/FaturaKayit.jsx");
var FaturaListesi = require("./React/FaturaListesi.jsx");
var FirmaDetay = require("./React/FirmaDetay.jsx");
var FirmaKayit = require("./React/FirmaKayit.jsx");
var FirmaListesi = require("./React/FirmaListesi.jsx");
var HesapDetay = require("./React/HesapDetay.jsx");
var HesapKayit = require("./React/HesapKayit.jsx");
var HesapListesi = require("./React/HesapListesi.jsx");
var KategoriKayit = require("./React/KategoriKayit.jsx");
var KategoriListesi = require("./React/KategoriListesi.jsx");
var KullaniciKayit = require("./React/KullaniciKayit.jsx");
var KullaniciListesi = require("./React/KullaniciListesi.jsx");
var MarkaKayit = require("./React/MarkaKayit.jsx");
var MasrafListesi = require("./React/MasrafListesi.jsx");
var ModalComponent = require("./React/ModalComponent.jsx");
var SelectList = require("./React/SelectList.jsx");
var SenetKayit = require("./React/SenetKayit.jsx");
var SenetListesi = require("./React/SenetListesi.jsx");
var TahsilatKayit = require("./React/TahsilatKayit.jsx");
var TanimKayit = require("./React/TanimKayit.jsx");
var UrunKayit = require("./React/UrunKayit.jsx");
var UrunListesi = require("./React/UrunListesi.jsx");
var Util = require("./React/Util.jsx");
```

My Kategori Listesi JSX

```js
var KategoriListesi = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function () {
        this.defaultColumns = [["Adi","Kategori Adı"],["Grup.Adi","Kategori Grubu"]];
        this.externalColumns = [["",EditRows]];
        this.dataUrl = "/Kategori/";
    },
    render:function(){
        return (<AjaxGridComponent dataUrl={this.dataUrl} filter={true} controllerName={'kategori'} showExternalColumn={true} externalColumns={this.externalColumns} defaultColumns={this.defaultColumns} />);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is this line: var sayfalar = require("./React/index.js"); ?

Comment: var FaturaKayit = require("./FaturaKayit.jsx");
var AjaxGrid = require("./AjaxGrid.jsx");
var AutoComplate = require("./AutoComplate.jsx"); .... my all jsx files

Comment: If Opp route works... and the others don't, it's probably the way you are exporting your other jsx files in './React/index.js'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `index.js` may be `require`-ing the components, but if you're going to access them like `sayfalar.SenetListesi`, then you need to make sure `index.js` *exports* those symbols, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  TanimKayit: require("./TanimKayit.jsx"),
  SenetListesi: require("./SenetListesi.jsx"),
  FirmaListesi: require("./FirmaListesi.jsx")
};
```

As you can see, having these in `index.js`, doesn't really provide any sort of convenience for you. Unless it's adding extra processing, you may be better off requiring the components directly.

Also, make sure the modules where you define your components are exporting the class. Otherwise, if you `require` them, you'll get `undefined`:

```
module.exports = React.createClass({ ... });
```

Finally, one thing that I did for *my* routes to avoid all those `require` statements is do the `require` inline, like this:

```
<Route name="DepoKayit" path="Depo/Kayit" handler={require('./React/DepoKayit.jsx')} />
```

Comment: i updated my question. i make like your said but not working

Comment: You should define those variables _before_ your function. Otherwise, they'll be `undefined`.

Comment: Also make sure your `.jsx` files export the classes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a problem on the sequence. see above. oppa is defined first while the others are after the router.run. hope helps!